# initialization const with inline function c

Tags: c, macros, constants, inline

i would like initialising const with macro or function inline.

i will try

```
STATIC INLINE uint16_t calcul_checksum_soft_Appli()
{
  uint16_t *l_adresse  = (uint16_t*)0x00001000;
  uint16_t l_checksum = 0;

  for (l_checksum=0;(uint32_t)l_adresse<0x00007FFE;l_adresse+=2)
    l_checksum+=*l_adresse;

l_checksum = ~l_checksum +1;

return (l_checksum);
}
const uint16_t Checksum __attribute__((at(ADR_CHECKSUM))) = calcul_checksum_soft_Appli();
```

==>function call is not allowed in a constant expression

or with define

```
#define \
calcul_checksum_soft_Appli() \
({ \
uint16_t *l_adresse  = (uint16_t*)0x00001000; \
uint16_t l_checksum = 0;\
for (l_checksum=0;(uint32_t)l_adresse<0x00007FFE;l_adresse+=2) \
    l_checksum+=*l_adresse; \
l_checksum = ~l_checksum +1; \
l_checksum;  \
})
```

==>expected an expression

i would like create in my ROM program data, checksum.

thank's.

Comment: Why don't you just compute the number and then set it to that number?

Comment: yes, but that does not progress and annoying for the future developer

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in C, unfortunately - it doesn't support compile-time execution of code. At best you could write a macro without loops or statements. If the variable `Checksum` is made local, the function call will work though.

However, that's the least of your problems. If you access memory like this, you might have to do it through volatile qualified pointers. Strictly speaking you can't even do pointer arithmetic on things that are not arrays. All of this code is undefined behavior.

Also, `~l_checksum` on a `uint16_t` will break on a 32 bit system, because of implicit integer promotion.

What you should probably do instead is something along the lines of

```
for(uintptr_t i=START; i<END; i+=2)
{
  uint16_t data = *(volatile uint16_t*)i;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on "~l_checksum on a uint16_t will break on a 32 bit system".  `l_checksum = ~l_checksum +1;` looks fine.

Comment: @chux On a 32 bit system, if the uint16_t has lets say value 1, it will end up as a negative number rather than 0xFFFE which was expected.